# varchar returning from tado query but dont know what to create my dataset field to for this varchar

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

Not sure if anyone can help me. 
I am new to delphi. And my objective is to write data returning of a TADO query to a dataset.
I have created a SQL TADO Query and in that query I am returning integers, Date and Varchars.

on the TADO Query, I needed to define the output parameter datatype, some of the options here, are ftword, ftstring, ftwidesting, ftfixedchar, ftwidefixedchar. But im not sure which one to pick. I tried most of these.

I also tried

dxMemData1RetailCalendarPeriod.AsString := adoTreeWindow.FieldByName('RetailCalendarPeriod').AsString;

If anyone can help me, that would be great. I searched everywhere and I cant seem to find what varchar matches to

Comment: Although you mention "output parameter type" you seem to be talking about the field type of a dataset field; they are not the same thing.  You can let Delphi choose the right field type for you.  In the IDE, double-click the dataset, then right-click in the pop-up and select "Add all fields" from the context menu.

Comment: I did that, it doesnt show me any fields here.

Comment: If it doesn't, it is because the AdoQuery is unable to execute the query defined by its SQL.Text property, so either there is an error in it, or its Connection property isn't properly configured..

Comment: @MartynA, Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: @MartynA, Thank you so much for your help so far. I manually added in the other fields and it picks it up. This is my sql below, its all the varchar fields im having trouble with. I dont know what to define varchar on the field parameter side. See sql below

Comment: SELECT RetailCalendarPeriodID,
        ID,
        ParentID,
        FromCalendarID,
        ToCalendarId,
         FromDate,
         ToDate,
         RetailCalendarPeriod --Varchar fields
  FROM @Hierarchy;

Comment: Well, if you are talking about columns of a Sql Server table, th normal choice for a VarChar column would be a TStringField with the same maximum size.  If it's an NVarChar field (Unicode), use a TWideStringField instead.  Btw what Delphi version and what SQL backend?

Comment: im using CodeGear™ Delphi® 2007 for Win32®  Version 11.0.2902.10471

Comment: im using CodeGear™ Delphi® 2007 for Win32®  Version 11.0.2902.10471 I added it as String on both sides. the dataset and my adoquery. Wow it works the only difference was actually entering the actually length. Thank you so much, you have helped me so much